# Is there a maximum number of subkeys in GnuPG?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, private-key, public-key-encryption

The GnuPG documentation describes a process to generate subkeys for a gpg-master-key with the option to have different validity settings for subkeys. This works perfectly for a small amount of subkeys, but i wonder if there is a limit of subkeys that can be created for a gpg-master-key?

Comment: Go and read the source code.

Comment: How could it make sense to have more than a few subkeys? One for encryption, one for signing, and..?

Comment: I read a bit into the source code, but there seems no obvious limit. However, i could be mistaken since i only have basic knowledge of C.